# How do I link against libtool static la library?

Tags: c++, makefile, libtool

I have compiled [this library](https://github.com/fclaude/libcds2) successfully. It generates a `libcds2.la` file that I am trying to link into my own project. I have all files (including the `.h` file) in the same directory as my project file. When I try to link and use the functions of said library, using:

```
g++ -o test -I/opt/include/ -L/opt/lib/ -lcds2 libcdsNoptrs.cpp util.cpp
```

comes back with

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libcds2.so.2: 
      cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

whatever that is. But the point is that most of the time it just doesn't recognize the library. I assume I'm doing something wrong with the file paths, but can't figure it out. My test file is a C++ file including `#include "libcds2/array.h"` and everything is installed in `opt/lib`, `opt/include`, ugly, I know, but that's what the Makefile generated.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did cds2 not produce a `libcds.a` and/or a `libcds.so` file?

Comment: The fact that the error names "libcds2.so.2" indicates that there's a "libcds2.so" symlink in your library search path pointing to this (nonexistent?) library.  I suggest you check that the library installed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libtool `.la` is a 'meta data' file. After building the `cds2` library, it's expected that libtool will also be used in 'link' mode to build any of the package's tests, etc.

Typically, the in the directory you find the `.la` file, you will find the `.a` and `.so` under the `.libs` subdirectory. The `.libs/libcds2.a` file will be found there, provided `configure` was given the `--enable-static` option (or it is enabled by default). But, my understanding is that you've installed the package in `/opt` :

```
g++ -I/opt/include/ libcdsNoptrs.cpp util.cpp -o test /opt/lib/libcds2.a
```

Otherwise, if `libcds2` isn't installed, just supply a path to: `.../libcds2/lib/.libs/libcds2.a`

Unless you want to use libtool in `--link` mode with `-static` to handle everything. But learning the advantages of libtool is usually an exercise for a rainy day:)