# libtool: convert/extract la to a

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, libtool

Is it possible to convert or maybe extract a file from .la library to .a?

I've a project where I have my application linked statically against all libraries, but some of them are generated with libtool (.la libs), while others are created with gcc (.a lib). In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32141076/4732868) one says, that in the .libs subdirectory should be .a libfile, but I've found there only .la, .so, and .o files, probably because the lib project was not configured with --enable-static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that in the .libs subdirectory should be .a libfile, but I've found there only .la, .so, and .o files, probably because the lib project was not configured with --enable-static.

That's what it sounds like to me as well.  You'll need to do that to get a `.a` file.  The libs you are building with `libtool` are probably being compiled with `gcc`.

> Is it possible to convert or maybe extract a file from .la library to .a?

No.  There's no object code in a `.la` file to extract to a `.a` file.  As the link to the other answer says, it's basically a metadata file of how to link and where the files are, etc.   A `.la` file is humanly readable, so if you really want to know what's going in there you can examine it.

Comment: If libtool is only a metadata file, and it can link without having .a library it means, that it has to link with all .o files, hasn't it?

Comment: For static libs, a `.a` file just contains `.o` files (e.g. [merging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3821949/425738) two `.a` files, showing the extraction steps and a creation step).  There's no linking going on in the creation of `.a` libs, just archiving, as that example shows.  Linking happens later when the executable is built.